# Android gradle build fails suddenly on ':app:mergeDebugResources' with no error messages

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

My gradle build stopped working completely out of the blue. Minute earlier it worked fine. Didn't change anything in gradle config files; as a matter of fact I was only changing application style in XML.
Make, clean and run produce:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> -1
```

Running gradle with `--stacktrace` produces:

```
Executing task ':app:mergeDebugResources' (up-to-date check took 0.031 secs) due to:
Task ':app:mergeDebugResources' class path has changed from 35ff0c585719dc5a2e2e4d58900e722a to 01ad85243d44a7018a6f6b671ff7bf6b.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED :app:mergeDebugResources 
(Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed.   
Took 0.155 secs.
```

Removing build directory didn't help, as well as cache invalidation and restart. Any ideas?

Using Canary (3.0) with build tools version 26.0.0.

### Update #1

Running with `--info --debug` hints:

```
could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
```

However, removing `google()` from config yields:

```
Received result
Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project '[project name]'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=3686, address=[e01105f7-0954-4e44-b561-3ac18fc3194f port:35854, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true, lastBusy=1499443736429, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=64f95479-4418-4e3d-948b-7481648b65df,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/iwoherka/.gradle/daemon,pid=3686,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
18:09:26.648 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
18:09:26.649 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
```

Comment: Try running gradle with `--debug --info`

Comment: "could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.". Well, that's strange.

Comment: You can use `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` instead of `google()`. Which canary release are you using?

Comment: Canary 5. It fails on LocationAwareException now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out that the problem was fonts in `res` directory instead of `main` which caused gradle to act very weird.